# How to create a list of named tuples from a very long JSON nested list?

Tags: python, json, namedtuple

The JSON-file looks like this

```
[["bla", "bla",] ["bla2", "bla2"] [..] [..]]
```

The JSON-file consists of hundreds of these list.

I need to get the `["bla", "bla"]` part out of the list and make it an named tuple.

how can I do this?

Comment: do you know the index of  `['bla', 'bla']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library for this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    lst = json.load(f)

# get the item from the list (and remove it)
item = lst.pop(lst.index(["bla", "bla"]))

# create the namedtuple you need
Strings = namedtuple("strings", ["str1", "str2"])

# generate a named tuple from the item
named_tuple = Strings(*item)
```